# Canvas Height & Width Problem

Tags: android, canvas

My Problem is I am Using Face Detector Example from Following Link but How To Find Square Height & Width and Replace Image on Square Same as Square Height & Width.Sorry for Bad English Communication.

http://downloads.ziddu.com/downloadfile/9930500/AndroidFaceDetector_files_100520a.zip.html

Please Help Me.

Comment: I have Edited My Question & Add Link into Question.

Answer (score 1):

Get the height and width from canvas.getHeight,canvas.getWidth respectively and then make a new bitmap with same size and set it to the canvas.
Hope this'll help you.

Comment: This will Return Emulator Resolution means 320*480.